# Javascript refresh php page when previous refresh has finished

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using this code to refresh a PHP page:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // This part addresses an IE bug. without it, IE will only load the first number and will never refresh
setInterval(function() {
$('.container').load('integra_data.php');
}, 2000); // the "3000" here refers to the time to refresh the div. it is in milliseconds.
});
// ]]></script>

<div class="container"><h3>Loading Data...</h3></div>
```

in javascript, rather than refreshing every X Seconds, can i make it refresh once the previous refresh has finished?

Comment: So it will refresh constantly without any delay or what? If ya, just use the load callback as: `refresh();
    function refresh() {
        $('.container').load('integra_data.php', refresh);
    }  `

Comment: i thought, ``document.ready`` means that the load has finished completely

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout instead setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.container').load('integra_data.php');
  }, 2000); 
});
```

`$( document ).ready(function(){})` everything inside of this will be ran after load of page has finished. so there should be delay of 2 seconds here..

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right you want to refresh the content of the div in an infinite loop, right? If this is right, you could pass your call to `load()` as `complete` callback. You could do somethin like this (recursion):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var loadFunction = function () {
    $('.container').load('integra_data.php', loadFunction);
  }
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
  loadFunction();
});
```

The `loadFunction()` will call itself every time the last run has finished. Refer to the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/load/) if you want to know more about the `complete` callback. If you add a little delay, since it's not always the best idea to make request as fast as possible use the `setTimeout()` function. You could add it to the `complete` callback.